# Different CSS-styling for different buttons

Tags: c#, css, asp.net-mvc

First and foremost; I know that a lot of these CSS-type questions have been closed, so, hopefully I've been able to broaden the question to fit others aswell. Here goes:

I've been handed a project and am doing my best with adding the features my boss wants me to. But when I try to style a button differently from the rest, the changes don't "take".

The css file works as I am able to style other things:

```
<link href="~/Content/Site.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

Button:

```
<input type="submit" value="Print." class="fakeBtn" id="fakeBtn" />
```

CSS tries:

```
.fakeBtn
{
    font-size: 0.8em;
    border: 0px;
    background-color: transparent;
    color: #999;
    cursor: hand;
}

input#fakeBtn
{
    font-size: 0.8em;
    border: 0px;
    background-color: transparent;
    color: #999;
    cursor: hand;
}
```

As you can see I've tried using a class to change the style and also the id approach. None of which works though. 
I've hardly done any mvc work and this, already existing, project is my first. Is it a logical error? What am I doing wrong?

**EDIT:**

Could any of these be overriding? These are all the css-snippets I could find with "input" in them. How does one know if something overrides something else?

```
input, textarea {
    border: 1px solid #e2e2e2;
    background: #fff;
    color: #333;
    font-size: 1.2em;
    margin: 5px 0 6px 0;
    padding: 5px;
    width: 300px;
}

    input:focus, textarea:focus {
        border: 1px solid #7ac0da;
    }

    input[type="checkbox"] {
        background: transparent;
        border: inherit;
        width: auto;
    }

    input[type="submit"],
    input[type="button"],
    button {
        background-color: #d3dce0;
        border: 1px solid #787878;
        cursor: pointer;
        font-size: 1.2em;
        font-weight: 600;
        padding: 7px;
        margin-right: 8px;
        width: auto;
    }

    td input[type="submit"],
    td input[type="button"],
    td button {
        font-size: 1em;
        padding: 4px;
        margin-right: 4px;
    }

input.input-validation-error {
    border: 1px solid #e80c4d;
}

input[type="checkbox"].input-validation-error {
    border: 0 none;
}
```

Comment: Strange, should work: http://jsfiddle.net/RzRHM/

Comment: It's working fine as you can see in [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/KQ9p5/). Use your developer tools to see if nothing else overrides your styling.

Comment: How does one know if some thing overrides? Please see edit @Morpheus

Comment: Concerning your question about overriding styles: the order in which css is applied follows certain rules (which I always have to Google). You can find it here: http://www.quora.com/In-what-order-do-CSS-definitions-take-priority (Quora! He posted a link to Quora! Let's get him! ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this is pure html, then your code seems fine, and it is clear that either your css is simply not being loaded and read, or it is being overwritten at some later stage.

You could try applying `important` (like `color: #999 ! important;`), just to see if any of the changes become visible then. If so, you know that the CSS properties are being overwritten somewhere else.

On the other hand, I've seen Asp.Net and MVC caching cause some problems here. You might want to try deleting the site and publishing again from scratch, to see if there are any changes.

**Update:**

I believe this might be your problem:

```
input, textarea {
    border: 1px solid #e2e2e2;
    background: #fff;
    color: #333;
    font-size: 1.2em;
    margin: 5px 0 6px 0;
    padding: 5px;
    width: 300px;
}
```

This specifies style for the type `input`, so if this comes after `.fakeBtn { ...}`, then that style will be applied instead  (unless ofcourse, you have added `! important;` to the end of some of the statements, in which case they will only be overridden by other statements which also contain `! important;`).

Your best solution is probably to add specific classes to the section: `input, textarea { ...}`. That way, it will not override other input-fields in general.

Comment: The only thing can be different from your update is `font-size`

Comment: @Morpheus I think you mean from my original answer? Well if you only apply that example, then yes, but that is why I used the word "like". Apply `! important;` to the rest of the properties too, and it should work.

Comment: I'm talking about adding both declarations in one place(`.fakeBtn` and the one in your update). _caching cause some problems here_ this might be an option

Comment: Caching was the issue. I cleared my browsers cache and now the changes are visible. Will this happen to the end user aswell? I mean, it wouldn't seem professional having a text stating "please clear your browser's cache for this website to load properly". And will I have to clear the cache every time I want to make a change to the layout?

Comment: Glad to hear you solved the problem. As for the caching, I'm not really sure. I suspect it might in some instances depend on the browser, and in others, on how Asp.Net/MVC presents in's data. In general though, this should not be a big problem. The cache will usually not last too long anyway, and the user will probably not notice even if he is presented with a slightly outdated version of a site (hopefully, you won't do major changes too often?). Personally, I've only (_knowingly_ at least) seen this happen locally while developing.

Answer (score 1):

CSS seems fine.

Try using Firebug to verify what styles are applied and what are overridden.

I suspect you have some other CSS rules that style the buttons and override your CSS.